# Running scala 2.12 on emr 5.29.0

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-emr

I have a jar file compiled in scala 2.12 and now I want to run it on emr 5.29.0. How do I run them as the default version of emr 5.29.0 is scala 2.11.

Comment: @dk14 That is false, since `2.4.0` **Spark** supports **Scala** `2.12` and since `2.4.2` it is the recommended version with `2.11` marked as deprecated. However, even if that was more than a year ago, most vendors like **AWS EMR** haven't updated yet.

Comment: Just curious. Why can't you recompile with 2.11 dependencies?

Answer (score 7):

As per this thread in [AWS Forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=902431), all Spark versions on EMR are built with Scala 2.11 as it's the stable version:

> On EMR, Spark is built with Scala-2.11.x, which is currently the
> stable version. As per-
> https://spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-2-4-0.html ,
> Scala-2.12 is still under experimental support. Our service team is
> already aware of this feature request, and they shall be adding
> Scala-2.12.0 support in coming releases, once it becomes stable.

So you'll have to wait until they add support on future EMR releases or you may want to build a Spark with Scala 2.12 and install it on EMR. See [Building and Deploying Custom Applications with Apache Bigtop and Amazon EMR](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/big-data/building-and-deploying-custom-applications-with-apache-bigtop-and-amazon-emr/) and [Building a Spark Distribution for EMR](https://github.com/aws-samples/emr-bootstrap-actions/blob/master/spark/examples/building-spark-for-emr.md).

#### UPDATE:

Since [Release 6.0.0](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-whatsnew-history.html#emr-600-whatsnew), Scala 2.12 can be used with Spark on EMR:

> #### Changes, Enhancements, and Resolved Issues
>
> - Scala
>
>   Scala 2.12 is used with Apache Spark and Apache Livy.

Comment: Being honest, I have been waiting for more than a year, is ridiculous that they haven't provided the support already. - Anyways, could you expand you question showing the step by step to build my own Spark and deploy it to EMR.

Answer (score 0):

Just an Idea, if waiting is not the option!

Is it possible to package the latest scala jars with the application with appropriate maven scope defined and point those packages with the spark property 
`--properties spark.jars.repositories` ??

Maybe you'll have to figure out a way to transfer the jars to the driver node. If s3 is an option that can be used as intermediatory storage.

Comment: Yeah, there's that... not sure if that can be resolved by an uber jar, need to try that out!